# How do I access the SelectedRow .NET MAUI desktop application?

Tags: c#, xaml, datagrid, maui

I have DataGrid thatWhat displays categories. What I'm looking do is place a second DataGrid on the screen and using MVVM and code-bedind, I want to take the selected rows from the first DataGrid and place it in maybe a foreach loop and select data from another table with matching category ID numbers.

I got the architecture of the code all worked out. My main problem is getting the SelectedRows property. Now, the DataGrid is from Syncfusion and I setup the xaml in the MainPage.xaml file. The code-behind is in the MainPage.xaml.cs file, but in that file I created another method like this:

```
public static DataTable GetPasswrds()
```

And this is where I want to access the SelectedRows property. I assigned the name of the first DataGrid to be GroupVw and this is where I get the problem. I try to access it by adding:

```
var selRows = GroupVw.SelectedRows;
int cntr = selRows.Count
```

Within the GetPasswrds() method and it can't even find GroupVw. If I place this code directly in the public MainPage() method, it works with no problem.

So how do I get access to the SelectedRows property of the GroupVw. I have heard about binding. Would this be an option? if so, how do I do it so I can get access from other parts of my program?

Comment: first, MAUI has no native `DataGrid` control.  Please provide a link to whatever package you are using.  Second, why is `GetPasswrds` static?  That is likely the root of your problem - you are trying to access an instance variable from a static method.  This is a basic C# issue.

Comment: I'm sorry. The DataGrid I downloaded was from [Syncfusion](https://www.syncfusion.com). After logging in and getting a license for it, I had to install the DataGrid from NuGet Packages and selecting Syncfusion.Maui.DataGrid. Thank you for the other information. I'll try removing static from the method and see how that goes.